# invalid use of undefined type 'struct data'

Tags: c

I am new to C language.
I'm currently trying to create an algorithm to make a rank of scores, following a textbook. This is a code shown in the textbook.

```
    void rank1 (struct data *x, int n)
{
    int i, j;
    
    for ( i = 0 ; i < n; i++ ) 
        x [i]. rank = 1;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    if(x [i].score < x [j].score)
    x [i].rank++;

}
```

Then I've got error saying below

```
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:1:20: warning: 'struct data' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
    1 | void rank1 (struct data *x, int n)
      |                    ^~~~
tempCodeRunnerFile.c: In function 'rank1':
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:6:11: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct data'
    6 |         x [i]. rank = 1;
      |           ^
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:6:11: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'struct data'
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:9:10: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct data'
    9 |     if(x [i].score < x [j].score)
      |          ^
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:9:24: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct data'
    9 |     if(x [i].score < x [j].score)
      |                        ^
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:10:7: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct data'
   10 |     x [i].rank++;
      |       ^
```

What can I do for this situation?

Comment: Have you defined the struct somewhere before this function?

Comment: Hey there, please share the whole code so that we can understand it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your struct has not been <s>defined</s> declared. When the compiler sees this function, it does not know what `struct data` means. Somewhere before this function, <s>define</s> declare that struct.

Something like this:

```
struct data{
   int rank;
   ...
};

<Your function here>
```

Comment: For the sake of correct terminology: He has to _declare_ the structure